# Emphasizing a noun using hyphening to create adjective

Tags: meaning, grammar, adjectives, syntactic-analysis

I am trying to emphasize the notion of (accumulation process) as an adjective using hyphening. I tried using *accumulative-like* but I am not sure if it does make sense!

My sentence is:

> This is accomplished by an accumulative-like training process by partitioning the large dataset into smaller subsets each fits the
>   memory.

I appreciate in advance any suggestion or modification

Comment: Consider  “incremental”.

Comment: see one more edit below, you should add a conjunction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Accumulative* is an adjective in itself. It expresses the quality or type of something that results in an accumulation.

So it should be enough to say:

> "This is accomplished by an **accumulative** training process by
>   partitioning the large dataset into smaller subsets **that** each fits the
>   memory."